# Helpers in Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper, rails-engines

I am working on a rails engine and I have a problem with the helpers.

Apparently this is a known "problem" but there's not a lot of solutions out there. The problem is that I have an AuthenticationHelper which I want to access globally - but it's not working.

I've [read that you could add a few lines to your `init.rb`](http://burmajam.blogspot.com/2009/11/helpers-in-rails-engines.html) but it does not seem to have any effect.

Any idea what the best way to make an application available in an engine?

EDIT: Fixed it- Just put the code (from the link) in the `engine.rb` instead.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you put in engine.rb?

Answer (score 10):

Put this code in engine.rb:

```
config.to_prepare do
  ApplicationController.helper(MyEngineHelper)
end
```

Comment: inside class Engine < Rails::Engine ?

Comment: For posterity: this is no longer necessary - rails now automatically loads all helpers

Comment: Running rails 3.2.12... Had to add this to access methods within ApplicationHelper

Comment: `/vendor/extensions/categories/lib/refinery/categories/engine.rb:11:in 'block in <class:Engine>': undefined method 'helper' for Refinery::ApplicationController:Module (NoMethodError)`

Comment: try `::ApplicationController.helper(MyEngineHelper)` or `ActionController::Base.helper(MyEngineHelper)` , maybe?

Answer (score 3):

To access main app helpers (ApplicationHelper) from engine's views I tried include this:

**app/helpers/your_engine/application_helper.rb**

```
module YourEngine
  module ApplicationHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper
  end
end
```

It works, but once, when I restarted dev server, it throws me `uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper`, but I can't reproduce this exception.

**EDIT**

Removed this `include` and made this one:

**lib/my_engine/engine.rb** (it's inside engine)

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    config.to_prepare do
      ApplicationController.helper(ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I had to change the .helper line in Rails 4.2 to this: ApplicationController.helper(::ApplicationHelper) ... That might even have worked with your first solution.

Comment: I follow this solution and application_helper works fine, but when I run `rails console`, I got "uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper (NameError)". Does someone knows the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this just in case:

I had the same problem using the [Administrate gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) with Rails 7. I wanted to access my main app helper modules.

Simply adding `helper all_helpers_from_path 'app/helpers'` in `Admin::ApplicationController` solved this. You can find the official documentation [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all_helpers_from_path).

My file now looks like this:

```
module Admin
  class ApplicationController < Administrate::ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_admin_user!
    helper all_helpers_from_path "app/helpers"
  end
end
```

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/334).